# Cannot provide array of objects in GraphQL mutation through Apollo

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby, react-apollo

I'm building app in Gatsby using Apollo to fetch and send data to CMS via GraphQL. All variables declared as `String`works as expected but when I try to send an array of 5 objects, in console it gets empty array. What's interesting, when I try to do the same operation through Insomnia, GraphiQL app or even Apollo DevTools, all variables work.

Here's my query

```
const ADD_REVIEW = gql`
  mutation AddReview(
    $name: String!
    $caption: String!
    $shopifyId: String!
    $rate: [Json!]
  ) {
    createReview(
      data: {
        author: $name
        caption: $caption
        shopifyId: $shopifyId
        rate: $rate
      }
    ) {
      id
      author
      caption
      rate
      shopifyId
    }
  }
`
```

here's array of objects I want to send through mutation

```
 const [stars, setStars] = useState([
    {
      key: 1,
      checked: true,
    },
    {
      key: 2,
      checked: true,
    },
    {
      key: 3,
      checked: true,
    },
    {
      key: 4,
      checked: false,
    },
    {
      key: 5,
      checked: false,
    },
  ])
```

and here's submit function

```
const [addReview, { data }] = useMutation(ADD_REVIEW)

.
.
.

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let shopifyId = 'new id'
    addReview({
      variables: { name, caption, shopifyId, stars },
    }).then((res) => console.log(res, data))
  }
```

Does anyone know where I made mistake?

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will post new issue on github

Comment: Your variable name has to be `rate ` as it's defined in the gql query, but you're sending `starts`

Comment: yeah, I've noticed it. Now everything works